# Android WebView Custom Error

Tags: android, webview

I want my app to be able to give my own custom error message if the app cannot connect to internet. I don't know what to do i try make a toast but does not working.

```
WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main );


    getWindow().setFeatureInt(  Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON); 


    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.MyWebview ); 
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   



    mWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebpage.html");

    final Activity MyActivity = this;
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
    {

        MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
        MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); 


        if(progress == 100)
            MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the Android WebView you can check if the device is connected to the internet. The following method returns if the device is connected or not:

```
public boolean isConnected(Activity activity) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

It's better to put this in a separate class. Before starting the Android WebView you can call this method. If it returns false, show a message asking the user to connect to the internet, otherwise simply open the link.

Comment: Please don't forget about the permission "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" in your Manifest!